# How to load an image in MATLAB without typing the whole path

Tags: image, matlab

I'm using `imread` yo read a file, but it requires the whole path

```
I=imread('E:\backup\Image Analysis\test_images\barbara.png');
```

I just want to type

```
I= imread('barbara.png');
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `barbara.png` is on your current search path, i.e. use the file-navigation bar to navigate to `E:\backup\Image Analysis\test_images\`, thus making it your search path.

Alternatively use [`addpath`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) to add it to your search directories:

```
addpath('E:\backup\Image Analysis\test_images')
```